# How to draw Timed Hybrid Petri Nets with tex?

Tags: graphics, diagrams, technical-drawing, automata

Reading [David, René, and Hassane Alla. Discrete, continuous, and hybrid Petri nets. Springer, 2010.](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-10669-9) I wonder how can one drow such thing in TeX: [image]

This is not a retirical question -  a technological one - I really would love to be capable to draw analogus images in LaTeX (using any library needed to generate .ps or .eps image or just drawing right inside document via some macros)

Comparing with TikZ [Petri nets examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/automata-and-petri-nets/) I do not get how t draw circle in circle (alike P5 and P6 places), is it possible to place automated tooltips with text and graphs alike in T3 and T4, how to create a connection like from P6 to T2?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Explanation of exact parts I am interested in is presented in 3rd paragraph!)